# I Have a message MySQL ERROR 1241 (21000) Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 'nama_pelanggan' column from the 'ms_pelanggan' table.

```
+---------------------+
| nama_pelanggan      |
+---------------------+
| Eva Novianti, S.H.  |
| Heidi Goh           |
| Unang Handoko       |
| Jokolono Sukarman   |
| Tommy Sinaga        |
| Irwan Setianto      |
| Agus Cahyono        |
| Maria Sirait        |
| Ir. Ita Nugraha     |
| Djoko Wardoyo, Drs. |
+---------------------+
```

The problem is, how do I display the name of the person who has the longest name (in the top row), and the shortest person name (in the next line). I tried using:

```
SELECT nama_pelanggan 
FROM ms_pelanggan 
WHERE LENGTH(nama_pelanggan) in (
  SELECT MAX(LENGTH(nama_pelanggan)), MIN(LENGTH(nama_pelanggan)) 
  FROM ms_pelanggan
);
```

but shows:

> ERROR 1241 (21000) at line 2: Operand should contain 1 column(s).

Can you help me find a solution?

Comment: Instead of in operator use between. Check syntax of Between operator.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky. You can do:

```
with
l as ( -- longest name
  select nama_pelanggan, 1 as o from t order by length(nama_pelanggan) desc limit 1
),
s as ( -- shortest name
  select nama_pelanggan, 2 as o from t order by length(nama_pelanggan) limit 1
),
r as ( -- rest of names
  select nama_pelanggan, 3 as o
  from t
  where nama_pelanggan not in (select nama_pelanggan from l)
    and nama_pelanggan not in (select nama_pelanggan from s)
)
select nama_pelanggan -- together now, sorted as requested
from (
  select * from l union all select * from s union all select * from r
)
order by o
```

Answer (score 0):

First select query will give you the one with max length and the second select query will give you the one with min length and
You can add Union in your query which will add the result of the two queries

Try this :

```
Select column 
from table 
order by length(column) desc 
limit 1
      Union   
Select column 
from table 
order by length(column) 
limit 1;
```